# MySQL stored procedure returns multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am a noobie to stored procedures. Now I have one that works, but I'd like to learn how to optimize it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`simonh`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_normalized_client_id`(IN source_id INT, IN source_division VARCHAR(255), IN source_currency VARCHAR(255), OUT NORMALIZED_ID INT, OUT NAME VARCHAR(255), OUT ADDRESS VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

IF source_id > 100000 THEN SET source_id = source_id - 100000; END IF;

SELECT
CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER INTO NORMALIZED_ID
FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id = SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;

SELECT
CLIENT.name INTO NAME
FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id = SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;

SELECT
CONCAT(IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STREET,''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_CITY,''), ' ', 
IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STATE_PROVINCE, ''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_ZIP, '')) INTO ADDRESS
FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id =  SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;

END
```

As you can see, I am using the same query 3 times to populate 3 OUT parameters.

My question is, is there a way to do it with only one query?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I see why INTO didn't work for me now. I got the syntax wrong.

Here's the working version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `t_get_normalized_client_id`(IN source_id INT, IN source_division VARCHAR(255), IN source_currency VARCHAR(255), OUT NORMALIZED_ID INT, OUT NAME VARCHAR(255), OUT ADDRESS VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

IF source_id > 100000 THEN SET source_id = source_id - 100000; END IF;

SELECT
CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER, 
CLIENT.name,  
CONCAT(IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STREET,''), ' ',    IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_CITY,''), ' ', 
IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STATE_PROVINCE, ''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_ZIP, ''))

INTO 
NORMALIZED_ID,
NAME,
ADDRESS

FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id = SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;

END
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the selects down to a single one.  And, I would recommend using consistent naming conventions for parameters -- so there is unlikely to be confusion with columns:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`simonh`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_normalized_client_id`(
    IN in_source_id INT,
    IN in_source_division VARCHAR(255),
    IN in_source_currency VARCHAR(255),
    OUT out_NORMALIZED_ID INT,
    OUT out_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    OUT out_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    IF in_source_id > 100000 THEN
        SET in_source_id = in_source_id - 100000;
    END IF;

    SELECT out_NORMALIZED_ID := CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
           out_Name := CLIENT.NAME,
           out_Address := CONCAT_WS(' ', CLIENT.OPERATION_STREET, CLIENT.OPERATION_CITY,
                                    CLIENT.OPERATION_STATE_PROVINCE, CLIENT.OPERATION_ZIP
                                   )
    FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE INNER JOIN
         ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT
         ON CLIENT.id = SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
    WHERE SOURCE.number = in_source_id AND SOURCE.division = in_source_division;

END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

In addition:

- I put the `IF` on multiple lines.  It is clearer that the `END IF` is there.  In general, I put "end"s of things immediately under the "beginnings" to ensure proper closure.
- `CONCAT_WS()` seems a better option than `CONCAT()`.  As a bonus, it also handles `NULL` values.
- I prefer the inline syntax of `:=` rather than `INTO`.  This is really just a matter of style.  `INTO` is used for other purposes, such as file access, so I think `:=` is clearer.

Comment: Perhaps the mysql I have is out of date, I got an error message:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
           out_Name := CLIENT.NAME,
    ' at line 12

Comment: MySQL client version: 5.5.29

Comment: if I change := to INTO, mysql throws another error: Undeclared variable: CLIENT

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do it like this?

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`simonh`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_normalized_client_id`(IN source_id INT, IN source_division VARCHAR(255), IN source_currency VARCHAR(255), OUT NORMALIZED_ID INT, OUT NAME VARCHAR(255), OUT ADDRESS VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN

IF source_id > 100000 THEN SET source_id = source_id - 100000; END IF;

SELECT
CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER INTO NORMALIZED_ID,
CONCAT(IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STREET,''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_CITY,''), ' ', 
IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STATE_PROVINCE, ''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_ZIP, '')) INTO ADDRESS,
CLIENT.name INTO NAME
FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id = SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;


END
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I got an error message saying CLIENT doesn't exist, which was declared in the INNER JOIN.

Comment: weird, are you sure your query is valid? try to execute your query that you wrote here in your question and see what you get.

Comment: I have this stored procedure working, and I just want to do an optimization.

Comment: does mysql version matter? AFAIK, it's a pretty old version.

Comment: MySQL client version: 5.5.29

Answer (score 0):

Between you Begin and End statements
    SELECT
    CLIENT.name INTO NAME,
    CLIENT.NEW_GROUP_REFERENCE_NUMBER INTO NORMALIZED_ID,
    CONCAT(IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STREET,''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_CITY,''), ' ', 
    IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_STATE_PROVINCE, ''), ' ', IFNULL(CLIENT.OPERATION_ZIP, '')) INTO ADDRESS
    FROM ccis_vendors.client_id SOURCE
    INNER JOIN ccis_vendors.receivable CLIENT ON CLIENT.id =  SOURCE.ACCOUNT_ID
    WHERE SOURCE.number = source_id AND SOURCE.division = source_division;